# Prove for all $x$, $x^8+x^6-4x^4+x^2+1\ge0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove for all $x$
$x^8+x^6-4x^4+x^2+1\ge0$

By completing the square you get
$(x^4-2)^2+(x^3)^2+(x)^2-3\ge0$

I'm stuck about the $-3$

Comment: I think this problem shows the limitations of completing the square for higher degree polynomials. It is much better to factor (via the rational roots theorem for example) in order to solve higher degree equations.

Answer (score 5):

Observe that $1$ and $-1$ are roots of your polynomial. You thus find that it is equal to

$$(x-1)^2(x+1)^2(x^4+3x^2+1)$$

and is thus clearly non-negative.

Comment: (if one observe  -1 and 1 are roots of the polynomial)

Comment: You mean "non-negative," not "positive."

Comment: sorry, i'm using frenglish here, corrrected :). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you have looks like 
$$x^8+x^6-4x^4+x^2+1$$
Which on rearranging becomes $$(x-1)^2(x+1)^2(x^4+3x^2+1)$$

Since the terms in the product are greater than or equal to  zero so the product itself is  greater than or equal to zero. i.e
$$x^8+x^6-4x^4+x^2+1\ge0$$

Comment: Yes, @amWhy, I thought to include inequality but I couldn't find when the term$ (x^4+3x^2+1)$ will become 0.

Comment: Okay Thanks@amWhy, I shall edit it.

Answer (score 2):

$x^8+x^6−4x^4+x^2+1$
$=(x^8−2x^4+1)+(x^4-2x^2+1)x^2$
$=(x^4-1)^2+(x^2-1)^2x^2$
$≥0 $

Answer (score 1):

Let $$P(x)=x^8+x^6-4x^4+x^2+1.$$

then

$$P'(x)=8x^7+6x^5-16x^3+2x.$$

but

$$P(\pm 1)=P'(\pm 1)=0$$

$$\implies P(x)=(x^2-1)^2(x^4+3x^2+1)$$

$$\implies \forall x\in\mathbb R \;\;P(x)\geq 0.$$

Answer (score 1):

By Descartes'  rule of signs, $x^8+x^6-4x^4+x^2+1$ has either 0 or 2 positive roots (counted with multiplicity). You can check that $x=1$ is a root and it is in fact a double root, which you can confirm either by factoring or by showing $x=1$ is also a root of the derivative. By symmetry, the only negative root is $-1$ (a double root).

Positivity thus follows from evaluating expressions at a few points. At 0 it is 1, at $\pm 10$ it is 100960101 and it is indeed positive in the three intervals $(-\infty,-1)$, $(-1,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$.